# Don't have back up

Tags: macos, itunes, icloud, applications, iphone

I deleted a photos and videos, also in recently deleted album. I don’t have the back up. Then after deleted my photos and videos, I reset my iphone. Its all gone.. Is there any way to recover it?

Answer (score 1):

Your only option after you reset the phone is to pull from a backup.  Due to the fact that all the devices are encrypted, there presently is no way to recover data from the phone once it has been deleted.